# Best way to have same interface methods with different parameters

Tags: c#, interface

So, I'm in the case were I have an interface called "IDamageable"
Now, I want to have multiple uses for that interface, for example, a method called TakeDamage, but with different options.

(TakeDamage(int) for the damage amount, TakeDamage(culprit) for who did it etc etc).

The thing is that I only want to implement one of there since I don't need the others in the class, and if they are in the same interface I must implement every case.

What would be the best way to do this? Multiple interfaces like IDamageable01, IDamageable02 etc etc or there is a better way?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what benefit the interface(s) will bring here. If you've got different options, and things only implement some of those options, then *callers* need to know how test which overloads the thing to be damanged supports, which somewhat defeats the point of using interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

No, you definitely don't need numbered interfaces nor interfaces that you partially implement. If you think you need that, you need to revisit your design.

You need one interface `IDamageable { void TakeDamage(int damage); }` and one interface:

```
public interface IDamageCalculator
{
    void ApplyDamage(IDamageable subject, int damage);    
    
    void ApplyDamage(IDamageable subject, Culprit damager);
}
```

Or something like that. You haven't explained enough about your domain to make this more specific.

Comment: I'm using Unity Engine, and an example of what I'm trying to do it's using a TakeDamage method called when the enemy hits the player, that passes its reference (Culprit) but when the player damages the enemy it passes how much damage depending on X factor, so its two TakeDamages, but each one should only implement one since it wont use the other

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Perhaps your methods shouldn't be void, but return something.

Answer (score 1):

You coud create a base class implementing interface, then your "real" calss extends base class and implement what you want.

Also, in order to avoid too many method you can use optional parameters when possible:

void foo(string x, string y=null);

Answer (score 0):

Create a new interface IDamager to handle this.

```
public class Bullet : IDamager
{
}

public class Char : IDamager , IDamageable
{
     public TakeDamage(int val, IDamager damager)
     {
         //here to do like:
         if(IDamager is Char)
         {
             Char c = IDamager as Char;
             //.... 
         }
         
         if(IDamager is Bullet)
         {
             Bullet b = IDamager as Bullet;
             //....
         }
     }
}

public interface IDamager
{

}

public interface IDamageable
{
    TakeDamage(int val , IDamager damager)
}
```